# iOS return values to the asynchronous javascript calls

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Below shown is js code which makes call to the native functions in iOS and Android, this function is called from another js method.Since the js calls to this function is asynchronous.we could not return any values in iOS.but in Android we could return the values  without any issue.In iOS control dosent wait until i get the response.Actually we are not suppose to modify this function call otherwise we can pass a callback method from the caller function.Please help me to solve this issue

```
VestaPhoneBridge.IsAvailable = function(featureName)
{
  if(isAndroid()) {
    if(typeof VestaJavascriptInterface !== 'undefined')
    {
      return VestaJavascriptInterface.isAvailable(featureName);
    }
    return false;
  }
  else {                
    bridge.callHandler('initiateIsAvailableFunction',featureName,function(response)  {
      return response;
    })
  }    
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about this line.

```
bridge.callHandler('initiateIsAvailableFunction',featureName,function(response)  {
  return response;
})
```

The problem will most likely be your `return`. The anonymous function you are passing as a callback will be called whenever the async request is finished. This means that it will be called by something inside the `callHandler` code path.

Your function is then returning to that function, and not the `VestaPhoneBridge.IsAvailable` function. Your callback should set values, and perform changes instead of returning a value.

**Example**

```
function Foo(callback) {
  callback(); // 42 is returned here, but not assigned to anything!
}

function Bar() {
  var baz = Foo(function() { 
    // You want to return 42. But here you are in a totally different function
    // scope! You are in the anonymous function's scope, not Bar, so you are not
    // returning anything to the caller of Bar().
    return 42; 
  }
  alert(baz); // Foo doesn't return anything, so this is undefined!
}

alert(Bar()); // This is also undefined, nothing was returned.
```

Comment: Hi Aesthete, Thanks for your answer. Do you mean using  callback function will be the only way to solve this issue?.

Comment: @user1878200 - I added an example, hopefully it helps you understand why what you're doing is broken.